# Moving absolute red dots when zooming an image

Tags: reactjs, position, state, zooming, scale

I have a little problem I can't seem to solve.
I have an image that I scale with an input range.
I go from 100% width to 150% width.

The problem is that I have on this image 
divs in absolute position that have to change position when I scale the image.

How do I do that?

Here's a sandBox to illustrate my problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-bogdan-0149c?file=/src/components/Carte/Carte.js

Comment: I'd suggest changing title to something like "pin elements onto an image with dynamic resizing", or at least less specific for your case.

Answer (score 1):

notice that dot is a child element of a container of `img`, not of the picture itself. Move `width`, add `position: relative` on container. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-faraday-qyhmx?file=/src/components/Carte/Carte.js

Also, it's helpful to simplify the problem you're faced with. One dot, no tooltips etc, remove code duplication. Divide and conquer. You'll have much more pleasant time